# comparing current list data with old list data

Tags: c#

I have to compare *current list* of data with *previous list* of data. In my list class i have

```
Id, 
Comment, 
Updatedby, 
Updated Dt, 
IsEdited
```

and few other fields. I am comparing like below.

```
foreach (var cscData in Currentcloses)
{
   if (cscData.Status == ReferenceEnums.ActionStatus.EDIT)
   {
      if (Previoussoftcloses != null)
      {
         foreach (var pscData in Previouscloses)
         {
            if (cscData.Id == pscData.Id)
            {
               //my logic goes here
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Is there any *better way* other than this. Just want to check.

New Code

```
 var currentData = Currentsoftcloses
                               .Where(c => c.Status == ReferenceEnums.ActionStatus.EDIT);

        foreach (var cscData in currentData)
        {
            if (Previoussoftcloses != null)
            {
                var previous = Previoussoftcloses
                            .GroupBy(item => item.Id)
                                .ToDictionary(chunk => chunk.Key, chunk => chunk.First());

                if (previous.TryGetValue(cscData.Id, out var pscData))
                {
                    //my logic goes here
                }
            } }
```

Comment: In what way better? More efficient, more readable, shorter? I think this question belongs to codereview instead of stackoverflow.

Comment: More efficient way

Comment: You can override Equals comparer for your type, and then use newList.Intersect(oldList) to receive the difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of *inner loop*; if `Previouscloses` is *long*, your code will be *faster*: `O(|Previoussoftcloses| + |Currentcloses|)` versus `O(|Previoussoftcloses| * |Currentcloses|)` time complexity.

```
// If Previoussoftcloses == null we can do nothing, let's check for this possibility
if (Previoussoftcloses != null) {
  // Dictionary is faster then List on Contains O(1) vs. O(N)
  var previous = Previouscloses
    .GroupBy(item => item.Id)  
    .ToDictionary(chunk => chunk.Key, chunk => chunk.First());

  // Readability: what we are going to scan
  var current = Currentcloses
    .Where(c => c.Status == ReferenceEnums.ActionStatus.EDIT); 

  foreach (var cscData in current) { 
    if (previous.TryGetValue(cscData.Id, out var pscData)) {
      //my logic goes here
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Dmitry,,I have updated my post. Is that correct way?

Comment: @Tronics: pull everything you can out of the loop: look, if `Previoussoftcloses == null` we can *do nothing* a good temptation to ckeck it as early as we can; we don't want compute `var previous = Previoussoftcloses.GroupBy(...)` *over and over again*, let's do it *before* looping.